# Creating a Custom DTD for Visual Studio

Tags: javascript, xml, visual-studio, custom-controls, dtd

I've got some custom templated controls which take JavaScript as template content, like so:

```
<ns:Custom runat="server">
    <contentTemplate>
        var a = new Array();
        for (var i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
            // do something
        }
    </contentTemplate>
</ns:Custom>
```

I want VisualStudio to treat the content of  exactly the same as it does  elements so that code coloring take effect and the validator doesn't puke on the "<" in the for-loop definition.

My understanding is that a custom DTD needs to be created to solve this. Does anybody know how to do this, have have links to resources for it?

Answer (score 0):

I admit I'm not familiar with VS templated controls, but this looks like XML (given the "ns:" namespace), and the standard way to embed left angle brackets inside XML, without them being treated as tags, is with CDATA:

```
<ns:Custom runat="server">
    <contentTemplate>
        <![CDATA[
        var a = new Array();
        for (var i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
            // do something
        }
        ]]>
    </contentTemplate>
</ns:Custom>
```